ASP.NET Core app scaling when processing high volume messages
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8.0 web application and C# 12, where I am consuming messages from multiple sources like RabbitMQ.
Earlier the number of messages are small like 50 a day even less.
Now the numbers of messages are more than 1000 a day, it will increase even further in future.
Currently performance of my application is degraded, it is loosing messages.
I do not have any cloud infra, or docker available in my organization. Only single server where I deploy my app.
I am implementing threading and async/await right now. Can you please suggest more options with application only to improve performance and scalability?
I tried multi threading, which helps.
I am expecting if am missing anything where C# or framework library can help more

1000 messages a day is nothing for a system like RabbitMq, it should handle thousands of messages a second reliably. But the devil is in the details, there is plenty of ways to do things poorly that can lead to issues. But your post is lacking any such details. To start with, what are you doing with the messages? any heavy processing? Any IO access like databases or disk? Have you done any profiling or benchmarking? How large are messages?

Yes am doing a lot of stuff with messages, parsing then processing then fetching data and then saving in DB. All these steps for each message.  No application did not have any profiling or bench-marking. messages are not so big, but on the basis of messages I need to do stuff, which in taking time from 2 minutes to 20 minutes depending on message to messages.

1000 a day is nothing for any system. That's not even 1 message per minute. We can't guess what the application is doing, but if 1 message takes 20 minutes, it's not the messages that are the problem, but the incorrect code for long running jobs. To avoid losing messages you need to store them while processing. A quick&dirty way would be to use a scheduling library like eg Hangfire to trigger jobs for each incoming message. Message busses like MassTransit and WolverineFX also offer the features needed for durable (Transactional) inboxes, tracking long multistep processes etc.

The RMQ client shouldn't block for a long time when receiving messages. In both console and web apps you can use BackgroundService to create a service that's up as long as the app is. The RMQ client could post the incoming messages to the queue and the service could process them one by one. That doesn't protect from crashes, it's just a way to avoid losing messages because the client is busy

Request times should typically be measured in milliseconds. If you have things taking several minutes you should start by figuring out why. It is fairly common that some simple optimization can drastically reduce processing times. Maybe you lack some database index, or use inefficient queries. Maybe the parsing is poorly done. But you cant fix a problem if you do not know what the problem is. Take a look at the profiling tools.
